# Enable/Disable particular input type on Mat checkbox event in multiple textboxes in loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

Please see the code where I have multiple each checkbox and a textbox in each of the row of the table. I want to enable disable the textbox on the basis of this checbox.  I tried several things but everytime it enables all the textboxes but not the particular row one where I have checked the checked box.  Please suggest me a way where I can handle this multiple checbox situation.

```
enableIncremental(event: any, id: any) {
if (event.checked) {

  console.log('in checked', event)
  this.tableData.filter(obj => {
    if (obj['schemaName'] + obj['tableName'] === id) {
    this.f['incrementalScript'].enable()
    }
  })

}
else {
  console.log('in uncheck')
  this.f['incrementalScript'].disable()
}
```

}

[image]

I tried multiple solution and really frustrated with this now.
Handling Multiple checkboxes in loop is becoming difficult in angular especially when to enable/ disable or check/uncheck any particular input type on the basis of some condition.
Please help me with a good approach.
ThankYou so much  :)